# How can I tweak Levenshtein distance in classifying linguistically similar words (e.g. verb tenses, adjective comparisons, singular and plural)

Tags: nlp, levenshtein-distance, similarity

I am out of ideas on how to complete this task. I am counting the frequency of a word, actually the base form of the word (e.g. running will be counted as run). I looked up on some implementations of Levenshtein distance (one implementation I run into is [from dotnerperls](http://dotnetperls.com/levenshtein)).

I also tried the double Metaphone, but it isn't what I'm looking for.

So, please give me some ideas on how to tweak Levenshtein distance algorithm in classifying linguistically similar words since the algorithm is only for determining the number of edits needed not considering if they are linguistically similar or not

Example:
1. "running" will be counted as one occurrence of the word "run"
2. "word" will likewise be an occurrence of "word"
3. "fear" will NOT be counted as an occurrence of "gear"

Also, I am implementing it in C#.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: I edited it as Rene suggested.
Another note:
I am trying to consider to consider if a word is a substring of another word but that implementation will not be as much dynamic.
Another idea I think is: "if adding -s or -ing to string1, string1 == string2, then string2 is an occurrence of string1." However, this is not the case as some words have irregular plurals.

Comment: And your exact problem with what you have implemented sofar in c# is?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to include it. My problem is how to exclude words that are not really similar in sense. Because in levenshtein-distance, fear and dear will be counted as similar word since it only need 1 edit. What i want is to tweak it into not counting those cases and also to include some words with 3 or more edits since making a verb into it's present tense will have more than 3 edits.

Comment: You really need to expand/enhance your question, even show the implementation code sofar, otherwise your question gets too many votes for closing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The task you are trying to solve is called [Stemming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming) or [Lemmatisation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemmatisation).

As you figured out already, Levenshtein-Distance is not the way to go here.
Common stemming-algorithms for english include the Porter- and Snowball-Stemmer.
If you google for that I'm sure you will find a C#-implementation of one of them.

Comment: Thanks, so it's called Stemming. I am just new in computational linguistics.

Comment: glad i could help :) this link looks like a good start for C#: http://www.iveonik.com/blog/2011/08/snowball-stemmers-on-csharp-free-download/